# Running gem install in a docker build hangs

Tags: docker, rubygems

I have a very simple **Dockerfile** with the following:

```
FROM alpine:3.2

# Install basic packages and Ruby
RUN apk update && \
apk upgrade && \
apk add curl wget bash tar ca-certificates && \
apk add ruby ruby-bundler ruby-rdoc ruby-irb

# Install Riemann-dash
RUN gem install riemann-dash

EXPOSE 4567/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-ex", "riemann-dash"]
```

When trying to build it, it hangs on the command `gem install riemann-dash`.
If I connect to this container from another terminal (`docker exec -it ID /bin/sh`) and run the `gem install riemann-dash`, it's fine!

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It hangs at generating sinatra documentation for a while. You probably don't need docs in the container image anyways. I'd install it with:

```
gem install -N riemann-dash
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! I figured it out by running with -V, which showed it was very slow in generating documentations. Adding the -N improved the run time.